# How to tell when a UICollectionViewCell disappears

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view where the cells contain `UIImageView`s, and I'm trying out adding a label as a subview to these views. The problem is that since the cells are reusable, labels keep getting added. I can, of course, check whether my label already exists and reuse it, but I'd really like to clean up after myself. Is there a way to tell when the cell disappears and remove the label then? I've looked at the various docs and don't find any methods that seem promising. Maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: What's your objection to using the label that already exists in a reused cell? You're resusing the cell object itself; why not its subviews? Or, if you've got a custom cell class already, make _it_ check whether the label exists when the controller tries to access it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Delegate method: `collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`

But you should probably just create a custom cell and reuse instead of creating and destroying...

Comment: OK. I already have a subclass of UICollectionViewCell that I'm using. It's not really doing anything at this point, though. The issue is that the collection view controller knows what goes on the label. The cell does not. I'll look up that and related delegate methods. I suspect that's what I need.

Comment: The cell shouldn't know, it just hosts the views and provides properties to access them - so they can be reused easily.

Comment: OK. So just like I have a property for UIImageView, I should add another property for UILabel. Then I just access it through cell.whatever in the controller. Right? I guess I need to wire it up in the storyboard, too.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Got it. I knew this already. I guess I just need a break. Thanks for helping me kick my brain back into gear. :)